# concise way to transform a node.js stream?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to convert a newline-separated JSON file to CSV (kind of a dumb task, but it doesn't matter), and am curious how I can easily do this in **node.js**. What I have so far is,

```
var csv = require('csv'), 
    fs = require('fs'),
    JSONStream = require('JSONStream');

var stream = fs.createReadStream('input.json', {encoding: 'utf8'})
    .pipe(JSONStream.parse());
csv().from(stream).to('out.csv');
```

This works, but doesn't let me express ordering on the keys. For example, if I have an input file like this,

```
{"foo": 1, "bar": 2}
{"bar": 3, "foo": -1}
```

I'd like to add a tranformer function,

```
function(line_object) { return [line_object.foo, line_object.bar]; };
```

so that my output will be lines `1, 2` and `-1, 3`, corresponding to `foo` being column 1 and `bar` being column 2, instead of the current behavior `1, 2` and `3, -1`.

However, all of the examples online seem rather verbose for adding transformers. They seem to create `require('stream').Transform` objects, and then set the `_transform` function on those objects. *Question*: Is there a cleaner / more concise way to do this? Thank you very much, and please forgive my ignorance as this is pretty much the first `node.js` code I've written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`event-stream`](https://npmjs.org/package/event-stream) might be useful:

```
var fs         = require('fs');
var csv        = require('csv');
var JSONStream = require('JSONStream');
var es         = require('event-stream');

es.pipeline(
  fs.createReadStream('input.json'),
  JSONStream.parse(),
  es.map(function(data, next) {
    next(null, [ data.foo, data.bar ]);
  }),
  csv().to('out.csv')
);
```